# javascript object declaration not working as i want it to

Tags: javascript, object, variable-declaration

I am creating a game, in which I declare the object `player` like so:

```
var player = {
    "id": "player",
    "displayText" : "<img src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png'" +
    "class='onTop' id='" + this.id + "' alt='you' border='0' />" + 
    "<div id = '" + this.id + "health' class = 'healthLost hide'></div>",
};
```

however, in `player.displayText`, `this.id` is returning `undefined`, why and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Where are you calling `this.id`? It might well be out of scope or context. Try `console.log(this)` to review your options.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha its in the object as you can see, 1 line after i declare `player.id`.

Comment: He asked about calling.  eg. where are you trying to get the value back out.

Comment: @Seano666: I misunderstood. He meant in `player.displayText`.

Comment: What if you try just id?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter i already use it in the `img` id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't change the current scope while creating an object literal, so `this` isn't what you think it is.

Make an object instead:

```
function Player(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.displayText = "<img src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png'" +
        "class='onTop' id='" + this.id + "' alt='you' border='0' />" +
        "<div id = '" + this.id + "health' class = 'healthLost hide'></div>";
}

var p = new Player('foo');
```

Comment: thank you very much do you think you can help me with this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556120/jquery-issue-with-dynamicaly-selected-elements

Answer (score 1):

```
var player = {
    "id": "player",
    "displayText" : "<img src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png'" +
    "class='onTop' id='" + player.id + "' alt='you' border='0' />" + 
    "<div id = '" + player.id + "health' class = 'healthLost hide'></div>",
};
```

You cannot use "this".. as it is bound to global object (like "window" in browser) .. If you know the name of object use.. objectName.this ..

I have used player.id above to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To get something like this you would need to setup a class as a function. Try this:

```
var player_class = function(){
    this.id = "player"
    this.displayText = "<img src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png'" +
    "class='onTop' id='" + this.id + "' alt='you' border='0' />" + 
    "<div id = '" + this.id + "health' class = 'healthLost hide'></div>";
}

var player = new player_class();
```

Have a look at some [Mozilla docs on this here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is related to function scope, uisng it inside the object decleration wont work. What you can do in this situation is something like this:

```
var player = {
"id": "player",
"displayText" : "<img src = 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-kAhN0HX-MBk/T_5bApfhbJI/AAAAAAAAAuI/lUww8xT9yV8/s1600/smileys_001_01.png'"
};
player.displayText += "class='onTop' id='" + player.id + "' alt='you' border='0' /><div id = '" + player.id + "health' class = 'healthLost hide'></div>";
```